# Changing map location from a thread in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, google-maps

I am making an android app about locating friends on map. So far I have the map up and running, and the fused location also running but from a different class which extends thread so the app will keep listening to location changed throughout its life cycle.

I have a problem when I initialize the map, the problem is either the locationListener will keep working but the map won't load, or the map will load but the locationListener will take a long time to get a new location.

I also have a problem when sending the current location from the Thread activity to the map activity so i animate the camera to a new loaction.

Here is the error i get :

> 12-22 23:22:38.847 17339-17339/com.example.swampsoftware.blbmonitor
>   W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x41ee6300) 12-22 23:22:38.852
>   17339-17339/com.example.swampsoftware.blbmonitor E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                             at
>   com.example.swampsoftware.blbmonitor.Maps.gotoLocation(Maps.java:232)
>                                                                                             at
>   com.example.swampsoftware.blbmonitor.GetLocation.onLocationChanged(GetLocation.java:81)
>                                                                                             at
>   com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzk$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
>                                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

So the problem happens once the method "onLocationChanged" is called.

I believe that this is a thread caused problem, but I don't understand what is the problem nor how to fix it, here is the code i made :

**Maps.class :**

```
public class Maps extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{


private GoogleMap mMap;

private Double locationLat;
private Double locationLng;

private Context context;


private static boolean isVisible;

// Defining parse object
ParseObject locationObject;

//Declaring Tabhost
TabHost tabHost;

public Maps() {

}

public Maps(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    isVisible = true;     
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gpslocation);

    // Initialize google map
    initMap();

}


// Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
// Initialize GoogleMap -> mMap
public void initMap() {

    if (mMap == null) {
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't start map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;  
}

// Method that saves current location
private void setCurrentLocation(Double lat, Double lng) {

    locationLat = lat;
    locationLng = lng;
}

// Get method for lng
public Double getLocationLat() {
    return locationLat;
}

public Double getLocationLng() {
    return locationLng;
}


// Method that animates the camera to a new location
public void gotoLocation(Location location) {

    LatLng ll = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, 15);
    mMap.animateCamera(update);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initMap();
    isVisible = true;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();   
    isVisible = false;
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    isVisible = false;
}

public boolean getIsVisible() {
    return isVisible;
}

// Method that is called when map is connected, initializes the locationRequest.
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {


}
```

And this is the Thread class that will keep listening to the new location using fused location :

**GetLocation :**

```
public class GetLocation extends Thread implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient; // Object that is used to connect to google maps API, must be built to use fused location
private LocationRequest locationRequest; //Object that requests a quality of service for location updates from fused location
public Context context;
public volatile boolean isRunning = true; // boolean to stop the thread loop

// Declaring location variables
private Double locationLat;
private Double locationLng;

// Declaring objects
private ParseData parseData;
private Maps maps = new Maps();
/***
 * run method for thread
 ***/
public void run() {

    //Initializing objects
    parseData = new ParseData();

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

public void terminate() {

    isRunning = false;
}

// Getters
public Double getLocationLat() {
    return locationLat;
}

public Double getLocationLng() {
    return locationLng;
}


/***
 * Auto-generated methods
 ***/
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    if (!isRunning) {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        return;
    } else if (location != null) {
        locationLat = location.getLatitude();
        locationLng = location.getLongitude();
        parseData.GetLocationParse(locationLat, locationLng);
        System.out.println(locationLat + " " + locationLng);

        // Check is map is active
        if(maps.getIsVisible()) {
            System.out.println("Maps is in foreground");
            maps.gotoLocation(location);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Maps isn't running");
        }
    }


}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    locationRequest = locationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(7000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

}

Thank you.

Comment: i Wonder if your location could be null cause u gave it from another Thread. Try some println goToLocation method to make sure. Then in GetLocation class i would make private Maps maps volatile. Or instanciate it somewhere else.

Comment: Please consider simplifying you location retrieval. Possibly with a library such as https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation. Also, there is no need to add the complexity of a thread. If your intention is to keep locations updating while your app is inactive, you should create a service instead. Lastly I don't see how your map implementation works as you instantiate a new map, which as far as I can tell, knows nothing about the map being shown.

Comment: Just noticed that maps is you Fragment Activity. Calling new Maps() is a big no go then! Look for other ways to communicate information in your app, singletons in Application class, callback interface, Handler threads, Event bus.. To name some options. But as said in the last comment, using an API to simplify location updates would help you a lot as you could get rid of GetLocation and keep all logic in Maps that way. Would be the easiest way to gain progress if android programming is new to you.